# How to use session in model of codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, session, change-password

I created a code for password change, in postman I should give old and new passwords with `userid`, when I create change password, but can't change password, it remains same in database and I think the problem is with session. Can someone see the error in my code?

**Controller**

```
  public function changepasswordcheckagain() {

    $arr = array();
    $arr['old_password'] = $this->input->post('old_password');
    $arr['new_password'] = $this->input->post('new_password');
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $result = $this->User_model->checkPasswordfor($arr);
    echo json_encode($result);
    if ($result) {

        echo json_encode('success');exit; 
    } else {
              echo json_encode($result);
        echo json_encode('fail');exit; 

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
  public function checkPasswordfor($arr)
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('userdetails');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    //$this->db->where('user_password',$arr['old_password']);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result();
    if($result){
        $layout['user_password'] = $arr['old_password'];
        $layout_data['user_password'] = $arr['new_password'];

        $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
        $this->db->update('userdetails',$layout_data, $layout);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: get any error message?

Comment: im getting fail and also false as errors even though i had given valid input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code: 
**controller**

```
  public function changepasswordcheckagain() {

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $arr = array();
        $old_password = $this->input->post('old_password');
        $new_password = $this->input->post('new_password');

        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $where = ['user_id' => $user_id];

        //$data['password'] ---> column name 
        //$data['password' => $new_password] ---> new value of column
        $data = [
            'password' => $new_password
        ];

        $result = $this->User_model->checkPasswordfor($where, $data);

        echo json_encode($result);
        if ($result == TRUE) {

            echo json_encode('success');exit; 
        } else {
                  echo json_encode($result);
            echo json_encode('fail');exit; 

        }
  }
```

**model**

```
   public function checkPasswordfor($arr)
   {
        $this->db->where($where);
        if($this->db->update('table name',$data))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
            return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: its showing error in model public function checkPasswordfor($arr) even when i changed to checkPasswordfor($where, $data)

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare User_model::checkPassword() in /var/www/html/sampleproject/application/models/User_model.php on line 94
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0000 235112 {main}( ) ../index.php:0
2 0.0001 238432 require_once( '/var/www/html/sampleproject/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' ) ../index.php:292
3 0.0314 791888 call_user_func_array ( ) ../CodeIgniter.php:514
4 0.0314 792320 Welcome->change( ) ../CodeIgniter.php:514
5 0.0315 792920 CI_Loader->model( ) ../Welcome.php:167

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Compile Error
Message: Cannot redeclare User_model::checkPassword()
Filename: models/User_model.php
Line Number: 94
Backtrace:

Comment: comment out this line ` $this->load->model('User_model');` in controller

Comment: @vak -hope you are happy with the answer give,please don't forgot to up vote if you are happy with the answer.