# codeigniter session not working in model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having issuing with session such after setting the session in my controller method, I be able to access in view but I cannot be able to access in model.

Here is the code:

```
public function get_username_ticket()
{
  $user = $this->db->dbprefix('users');
  $kq=$this->session->t_bys;
  $sql = "SELECT $user.*
          FROM $user
          WHERE $user.deleted=0 AND $user.id = $kq";
  return $this->db->query($sql)->row();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910185/how-to-use-session-in-model-of-codeigniter

Comment: In case, i also get the same issue. Please anyone have an answer..?

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve by:

```
$this->session->userdata('sessionVariable');
```

Comment: I have tried to use both method and its not working for me.

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter you are using ? Also, can you update your question with setting session line of code?

Comment: the most funny thing is that when I change and use another table field its working but when I use  created_by field thats where everything fails

Comment: $ticket_info = $this->Tickets_model->get_details($options)->row();
    
        $this->session->set_userdata('t_bys',$ticket_info->created_by);

Comment: $this->session->userdata('t_bys'); have you tried this ?

Comment: anyone please with an idea because its working well in view file

Comment: Alternate, you can get session in controller and pass along the function to model.

Comment: it worked for a while but once I change the session variable it again refuses to work. I dont really understand what is these all about.

Comment: Maybe predefined keyword issue.

Comment: I have even tried abcd as a session variable but its still misbehaving

Comment: have you add session library in autoload.php. To get access in all the file

Comment: @ChaitanyaDesai: I am sure he had, that's why he is getting other variable which stored in session.